# How can I cancel a method after certain amount of time?

Tags: ios, xcode, dispatch-async

I have a simple app that basically runs a method that fetches an live HTML data which then extracts some info using xpath query after a button is pressed.

Sometimes it hangs during the fetch, so what I 'm looking to do is to cancel the method then run another method (to show a button to "try again") after certain amount of time is passed.

I have tried using dispatch_async to run a method over the current one but I had no luck, as it still completes its run after dispatch_async is called. So I'm thinking cancelling the original method would stop this from happening.

What would be the best approach to solve this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Note : I am not using NSURLRequest at all atm.

Comment: Use `NSOperationQueue` instead of `GCD`

Comment: If you aren't using NSURLRequest, what are you using?

Comment: @Jim I'm passing over to NSdata using dataWithContentOfURL

Comment: @Pawan-Systematix Thanks for that. I've tried it just now but it doesn't seem like it's executing the method correctly. I've tried it this way :

`NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
 
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
    selector:@selector(methodToCall)
    object:objectToPassToMethod];
 
[queue addOperation:operation];`

Comment: In this case I don't think it will be possible to cancel operation.

Comment: I've now changed the code to use `NSURLRequest` (Was easy!) Would it be possible to perform such task now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by implementing NSURLConnection. Because the data is downloaded asynchronously, I also implemented CFRunLoop on the connection and on connectionDidFinishLoading to run the method after it receives all data from the connection.

Hope this helps someone out there!